# How do I mark my package as depending on ghc specifically?

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal

My package depends on some implementation details in GHC (more than just language extensions). How should I express this dependency in my .cabal file? Should I? Am I just being paranoid?

### `build-depends`

I thought that maybe I should just add `ghc` to the `build-depends` list, but there's no [ghc package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc).

Inspired by [ghc-mod's dependency list](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-mod), I tried it anyway. I added `build-depends: ghc >= 7.20`, and this produced the expected failure when I only had 7.10.3 installed. (7.20 doesn't even exist as of this writing.)

```
cabal.exe: At least the following dependencies are missing:
ghc >=7.20
```

Is `ghc` some sort of magic package? What are the other magic packages?

### `tested-with`

There's the [`tested-with` package property](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/developing-packages.html#package-properties). That doesn't seem affect the build, however. I added `tested-with: GHC==7.20` (a version of GHC that doesn't exist but newer than the 7.10.3 I have), but `cabal build` still built my package and didn't even issue a warning or anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ghc` *is* a package, and not a magic one. It is just not a package on Hackage. Rather it is installed with your ghc install, and hidden by default. You can see it listed in the output of `ghc-pkg list`. It exposes an API for the compiler. If you don't actually use it, you shouldn't depend on it. In general, most people *don't* pin themselves to GHC unless they actually need to. For example, are you *sure* your package won't compile with `GHCjs` or with `Haste`? So, why limit yourself ahead of time...

If you can use your package without the implementation details in ghc, but can also do things in a "longhand" way that is more expensive, you can use the macros provided by cabal to have CPP conditionals in your code that give different results based on the test for GHC.

`tested-with` is indeed a purely informational field used by convention.